# sqlcmd in shell script loop

Tags: linux, shell, sqlcmd

Hi I have a shell script that inserts disk status of linux servers in SQL server. Before inserting the SQL command, the program executes and ends properly. However, when I inserted the SQL command, the .sh file never goes to the next line to execute. It is always in a loop. Kindly help

```
#!/bin/bash

#Functions here
insert() {
echo "--INSERT FUNCTION--"
echo "$1"

fsname=$1
fs=$(echo "${fsname: -3}")

 sqlcmd -S <ipadd> -U <user> -P <pass> -d tech_admin -Q "EXEC insertDiskStatus $fs"
sleep 1

}
echo "TEST"
cd ~/Documents
pwd
df -Ph --exclude-type=tmpfs --exclude-type=ext3 --block-size=GB | column -t |         sed 1d > diskspace.log
filename=diskspace.log

while read -r line
do
 this=$line

 fs=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')

 insert $fs 

done < "$filename"
```

Comment: I tried to put return at the end of function, but it still continues to loop

Comment: What do you mean "continues to loop"? What happens exactly?

Comment: its stuck in sqlcmd... please help :(

Comment: never goes to the next line of command.

Comment: if there's an echo after the sqlcmd, it wont execute that command.

Comment: Can you run that `sqlcmd` command manually and have it work (and return) correctly?

Comment: tried it manually and was able to insert successfully :)

Comment: Does it work if you add `< /dev/null` to the `sqlcmd` line?

Comment: Wow!!! It worked! Thank you so much :-) What does the <  /dev/null do?? :D

Comment: Redirects standard input for the command from `/dev/null` instead of having it read from the normal standard input (in this case the `$filename` file from the redirection outside the loop). Why that would cause the command to hang I'm not sure but presumably it was either processing the data or stuck on EOF or something.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. In my bash script, I have sqlcmd in a while loop and the loop would continue running the first item in the list over and over and not continue on to the next item. As mentioned in the comments, adding this  `< /dev/null` to the end of sqlcmd line will cause it to get out of stuck spot in the loop and carry on to the next tiem.

Comment: thanks for this answer! any idea why sqlcmd is doing this ?